# Squid: how to block websites for a particular IP address?

Tags: linux, proxy, ip, squid, blocking

How to block websites for particular IPs by squid?

Please give solution with example or configuration file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Example :

I blocked Facebook & orkut to all user but now i want to open only facebook to particular user or IP

---

**Option 1 : Specify site with in configuration file,**

> acl special_clients src "/etc/squid/special_client_ips.txt"
>
> acl facebook dstdomain .facebook.com
>
> acl orkut dstdomain .orkut.com

Under http access

> http_access allow facebook special_clients
>
> http_access deny facebook
>
> http_access deny orkut
>
> http_access allow all

---

**Option 2 : Stick both client IP s and destination domains into lists,**

> acl special_clients src "/etc/squid/special_client_ips.txt"
>
> acl bad_domains dstdomain "/etc/squid/bad_domains.txt"

Under http access

> http_access allow bad_domains special_clients
>
> http_access deny bad_domains
>
> http_access allow all

- I get it from net, It work very well
- Thanks cstamas

Answer (score 5):

You need somthing like this:

```
acl BlockedHost src 192.168.1.15
http_access deny BlockedHost
```

The config file is well commented searching for the word **acl** will help you further.

[Squid acl faq](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl)